# I want to use a field from database as a dropdown when I use get api

Tags: php, html, css, ionic4, angular8

page.ts

```
getData() {

    var link = 'http://servername/databasename/.php';
    var data = JSON.stringify({});

    this.http.post(link, data).subscribe(data => {
        if (data == 0) {
            this.data = false;
        } else {
            this.data = true;
            this.result = data;
            console.log(this.result);
            this.result.leavetype;
            console.log(this.result.leave_type);
        }
    });
}
```

page.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="medium">Leave</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="leavetype" name="leavetype">
        <ion-select-option value="">{{leave_type}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

After this, I got my result in Array form in this array I had a field named leavetype. I want every value of this field in my dropdown. Will you please help me about my code. I hope you understand my problem thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "*ngFor" in ion-select-item

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="medium">Leave</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="leavetype" name="leavetype">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let val of result" value="">
            {{val. leavetype}}
        </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```